# .NET Coreのプログラムをサービスで動かす方法

Tags: c#, .net

.NET CoreのプログラムをWindowsでサービスとして動かす方法、Linuxのデーモンとして動かす方法をそれぞれご存じの方がいましたらご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linuxの場合は supervisor を使うか nohup を使えばデーモンプロセスとして動かせるかと思います。